# Component Services (Win2k3sp2) Won't Start Due to Permission Settings

Tags: com, windows-server-2003, dcom

In Windows Server 2003 SP2, I have removed all users (Anonymous Users, Authenticated Users, Everyone etc) under Component Services > Computers > My Computer > Properties > COM Security > Edit Limits.

After that, I couldn't access the server via remote desktop and terminal services also fails. I can still access it via VNC but when I attempt to open Component Services > Computers, the window stops responding.

Is there any way that I can restore COM permissions to their default settings at least? Or is there a way to enable access to the properties window so I can set it myself?

Thank you for your help.

Ianthe

=== Update: DCOMPERM.EXE ===
I found that the dcomperm.exe file that can alter permissions via the command line. It works on my local machine. My problem now is how to copy it over to the Win2k3 server since network services (netlogon etc) fails to start.

The idea I have right now is to access the Win2k3's VM hard disk and copy the file over. I have yet to find a way to do that.

If you guys have a better way, I hope you don't mind helpin.

Thanks again!

Comment: I was able to use Subversion to move files from my client machine to the server. It was able to fix the "hanging" Component Services window. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the dcomperm.exe that can alter permissions via the command line. It works on my local machine. Please note that netlogon service also fails to start due to the permissions. I wasn't able to transfer the file through shared folder.

A workaround I did, is use subversion to transfer the file. Commit-Checkout/Update...

After I reset the permissions, the Component Services window worked as per normal.